# Error submitting job Arcgis server

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

I am trying to execute service tool that written in python with arcpy.
When I am executing the service I got submitted...
Executing...
Failed.
I looked the logs, and I got there:
Failed to execute(script_name)
Error executing tool.

I tested that, and I realized that the script not even start to run.
I tried to remove and publish several times with differences, and got nothing.

Details:
Windows server 2012 R2
Arcgis server 10.3

---

After a lot of tests, I realized that this one line of code makes it fails.

```
arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(out_folder_path, out_name)
```

The thing is, I executed it on my computer and it working(that's why I published it successfully)
Only at the server it's not working.

---

The main problem is the createFileGDB_management function. Somebody knows why it doesn't work in the when executing Arcgis service tool in the Arcgis server?

Comment: Please edit the question to include your code.

Comment: I didn't include my code because I proof it's failed before the code began. I added arcpy.AddMessage to it, and no messages appears.

Comment: Messages are only displayed if the service is configured to display messages.  Is it?  The default is NONE.

Comment: How I check it?

Comment: Manager, service, Parameters -> Properties -> Message Level

Comment: Add arcpy.AddMessage(out_folder_path) and arcpy.AddMessage(out_name) in the script just before creating the geodatabase. This will show up in the execution log for the GP task.

Comment: I did it. The path's correct. The main problem is the createFileGDB_management function. Do you know why?..thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you get as messages after setting the log level to Info for GP service (look in Results window in ArcMap) and log level for AGS to Debug (look in AGS Manager)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is the Arcgis service.

We have ran it as local system user instead of the machine user. Thus, it couldn't create nothing beside the local machine(I tried to create file gdb at network driver).